# Parsing file paths with `find` in a shell script treats spaces as newlines

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that just makes ffmpeg convert .flac files to .ogg.

```
find $1 -name '*.flac' | while read -r i; do
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 6 ~/"$i".ogg
done
```

It fails when it encounters a directory with a space in its name and splits it by the newline. e.g. `/path/to/this dir` becomes `/path/to/this` and `dir`.

I've tried piping into xargs but that doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: When you say "encounters", do you mean that `$1` contains spaces already? If so, then obviously you need to put that in quotes.

Comment: In addition, you may run into `ffmpeg` stealing input from the file list; see [BashFAQ #89: "I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: From the bash man page about the `read` command: _One line is read from the standard input ... , **split into words** ... and the **first word** is assigned to the first name_.  So, what else would you expect?

Comment: If you don't want to fiddle with IFS to inhibit word splitting, you could use `readarray` to put the output of `find` into an array, and then loop over the array. Note that this would still not work, if you have filenames with embedded newline characters (which could indeed occur with music files).